# Using subset of Lie algebra to construct group elements

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Suppose one takes a few, but not all, elements, $a_i \in \mathfrak{so(n,m)}$ and finds a matrix representation, $m_i$, for each $a_i$ that satisfy the same bracket properties which $a_i$ follow, then uses the exponential map to obtain $g_i \in SO(n,m)$.

Is is possible that the product $g_i^T \cdot g_i \neq 1$? In other words, even though $g_i$ cannot be any arbitrary element of $SO(n,m)$ but it must still be an element of it, & hence follow the properties of any element belonging to $SO(n,m)$, generated by the subset $a_i$ even though $a_i$ don't exhaust the list of all possible generators?

Thanks!

Edit : to provide some context, I've been told that if one works with non-unitary representations then the above may not be true.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic I've asked a moderator to help me migrate it, I thought asking it here would get me results in a language more comprehensible to me

Comment: Could you explain more precisely how the $g_i$s are constructed? If they are exponentials of the $a_i$s, then the $m_i$s are irrelevant, but if the $g_i$s are exponentials of the $m_i$s then the $g_i$s don't need to be elements of $SO(n,m)$ (since you didn't say what kind of matrices $m_i$ are; they could be matrices of different sizes than the $a_i$s are, if I'm reading you correctly).

Comment: @coiso right, so $g_i$s are exponentials of $m_i$s and $m_i$s, matrix representations of $a_i$s, follow the same Lie algebra that $a_i$s follow - is this not sufficient to guarantee that $g_i$s will be elements of $SO(n,m)$? Actually, my group is either $SO(2,3)$ or $SO(5)$ and $m_i$s are $4 \times 4$ matrices. Also, let's just forget about $m_i$s, if I just exponentiate $a_i$s then I must get an element of $SO(n,m)$, right?

Comment: If you exponentiate the $a_i$s you get elements of $SO(n,m)$, yes. If for instance $m_i$s are $4\times4$ then their exponentials are also $4\times4$ matrices which cannot be elements of $SO(2,3)$ or $SO(5)$.

Comment: @coiso right, that's a very clear way to see that - also, if we work with non-compact real form of an algebra then exponentiating the algebra elements won't yield elements of the group associated with the algebra, right?